# How to center inputs in a form with labels on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a form, some labels and inputs.

The design calls for the "inputs" to be centered in the page. The labels are inline with the inputs and right-aligned.

Note: the labels are not included in the centering, they float to the right. See example below.

[image: form layout example]

Here is what I have for the layout.

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 102px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.input {
  width: 172px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid $black;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<h1>Inputs should be centered</h1>

<form action="/" method="post">

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="name" class="label">your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="email" class="label">email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input">
  </div>

</form
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the ***Flexbox*** / ***positioning*** combination:

```css
.input-wrap {
  position: relative; /* needs to be set on the parent element */
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.label {
  position: absolute; /* positioned relative to the parent element; taken out of the normal document flow */
  left: -117px; /* moved left by negative 102px (width) + 15px (margin-right) because the default value is 0 */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 102px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  /*margin-right: 15px; not necessary anymore, i.e. has no affect on label elements*/
}

.input {
  width: 172px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid $black;
}

form {
  display: flex; /* displays children (divs) inline by default thats why you need to change its direction */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks children vertically */
  align-items: center; /* horizontal alignment / centering / affects only input elements since label elements are taken out of the normal document flow */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Inputs should be centered</h1>

<form action="/" method="post">

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="name" class="label">your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input">
  </div>
  
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="email" class="label">email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input">
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.input-wrap {
        width: fit-content;
        height: fit-content;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 22px;}
```

Comment: That centers both the label and input doesn't it? I need just the input centered.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate to the solution using flexbox would be to set a width on your form and make your `label` and `input` widths percentage based. The following will work for all screen sizes whereas the flexbox solution will only work on screens larger than ~400px, anything smaller than that will begin to cut off the label text.

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid $black;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 44px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 24px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .label {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .input {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Inputs should be centered</h1>

<form action="/" method="post">
  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="name" class="label">your name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input">
  </div>

  <div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="email" class="label">email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nice, that works as well. I marked @VXp as the correct answer, since that was what I used. But +1 for an alternate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<form action="/" method="post">

 <center>
   <div class="input-wrap">
     <label for="name" class="label">your name</label>
     <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input">
   </div>

   <div class="input-wrap">
     <label for="email" class="label">email</label>
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input">
   </div>
 </center>

</form>
```

Or you can center a `div` using this css code:

```
.input-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: That centers both the label and input. I want the inputs to be centered. @VXp had the correct answers.